# Tagging several friends in facebook using graph api

Tags: iphone

`[delegate.facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/tags?tags=[{\"tag_uid\":\"%@\"},{\"tag_uid\":\"%@\"}]&access_token=%@", photoID, @"100004392816950", @"100001982573649", delegate.facebook.accessToken]    andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`

This code i am using for tagging several friends but it doesn't work.

When I run the program I get following error:

```
ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error 
Domain=NSURLErrorDomain 
Code=-1000 "bad URL" 
UserInfo=0x14cabf10
```